# How to define local variable in a select LINQ-query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I try to write this code:

```
returnModel.BunkerStat=tmpBunk.Select(b =>
                 new BunkerStatisticsRowModel
                 {
                   numberOfBunk=b.NumberOfBunk,
                   procentOfBunk=numberOfBunk/100
                   }).ToList();
```

But I get compile error because I cant reuse numberOfBunk to calculate procentOfBunk. Anybody know How I can reuse numberOfBunk? I dont want to repeat b.NumberOfBunk. Thanks.

**SOLVED:**

I tried like this and it worked:

```
returnModel.BunkerStat=tmpBunk.Select(b =>
                     new BunkerStatisticsRowModel
                     {
                       numberOfBunk=b.NumberOfBunk,
                       procentOfBunk=numberOfBunk/100
                       }).Select((p)=>
            new BunkerStatisticsRowModel()
            {
               numberOfBunk=p.numberOfBunk,
               procentOfBunk=p.numberOfBunk/100

             }).ToList();
```

Comment: You can't use property of BunkerStatisticsRowModel from within its constructor since you do not have a reference to it yet.

Answer (score 4):

Use lambda with body

```
returnModel.BunkerStat = tmpBunk.Select(b => {
    var procentOfBunk = b.NumberOfBunk / 100;
    return new BunkerStatisticsRowModel
    {
        numberOfBunk = b.NumberOfBunk,
        procentOfBunk = procentOfBunk
    };
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: NumberOfBunk is diffrent for every BunkerStatisticsRowModel then I cant define it outside return new BunkerStatisticsRowModel
    {\

Comment: I dont see any difference with alexander soultion and using same procentOfBunk  =  b.NumberOfBunk / 100 , can i know why we need local variable ?

Comment: @RanjithMurthy See question's title "How to define local variable in a select LINQ-query"

Comment: @Alexander yes i see your soultion with local variable inside linq block, but still same effect , with local variable or without local variable (using   the b.NumberOfBunk ). I dont see its optimal.

Comment: When you use a multi line lambda (`b => { }`) you have to add `;` at the end of every statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to add Properties in your Model BunkerStatisticsRowModel.

```
   public class BunkerStatisticsRowModel
    {
        public int procentOfBunk { get { return numberOfBunk / 100;  } }
        public int numberOfBunk { get; set; }
    }
```

Then use your linq statement like this.

```
returnModel.BunkerStat=tmpBunk.Select(b =>
                 new BunkerStatisticsRowModel
                 {
                   numberOfBunk=b.NumberOfBunk
                   }).ToList();
```

you should have your Collection which contains numberOfBunk and procentOfBunk.

Comment: This is not optimal, because you are calculating ```numberOfBunk / 100``` everytime you access ```procentOfBunk ```. Better solution would be ```public class BunkerStatisticsRowModel
    {
        private int tmp;
        public int procentOfBunk { get; private set; }
        public int numberOfBunk { get => tmp; set =>{
            procentOfBunk = value / 100;
            tmp = value;
        }; }
    }```

Answer (score 1):

You can use statement lambda to create a temporary variable.

```
returnModel.BunkerStat = tmpBunk
                .Select(b =>
                    {
                        var procentOfBunk = b.NumberOfBunk / 100;
                        return new BunkerStatisticsRowModel
                        {
                            numberOfBunk = b.NumberOfBunk,
                            procentOfBunk = procentOfBunk,
                        };
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: NumberOfBunk is diffrent for every BunkerStatisticsRowModel then I cant define it outside return new BunkerStatisticsRowModel {\ }

Comment: Select linq function processes each item in the sequence. And for each of them calls the lambda in the body. The variable "procentOfBunk" is disposed when its scope ends.